# Getting ith element of a sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am currently learning clojure and I need help.
Say if I have below which is p,

```
{:variable "x", :coef (2 5 7 13)}
```

I can access coef by doing `(last (last p))` and can iterate range of it by doing

```
(for [i (range(count (last (last p))))]
        i
        )
```

Now, I want to access each ith coef elements. For example if i is 0, then I want to get 2, if i is 3, then I want to get 13).

Comment: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nth

Comment: You should use `(:coef p)` or `(get p :coef)` to access the key `:coef`. Small maps maintaining keys in declaration order is an implementation detail you can't rely on.

Comment: I discarded the `lazy` from `lazy seq` in the title, because this question has nothing to do with a lazy seq.

Answer (score 4):

Using the same definition of `p` you currently have:

```clj
user=> (def p {:variable "x", :coef '(2 5 7 13)})
#'user/p

user=> (defn nth-coef [p i] (nth (get p :coef) i))
#'user/nth-coef

user=> (nth-coef p 0)
2
user=> (nth-coef p 1)
5
```

If `p` had a `vector` in the coefficients, you could use `get-in`:

```clj
user=> (def p {:variable "x", :coef [2 5 7 13]})
#'user/p

user=> (get-in p [:coef 1])
5
```